# Getting input into a linked list using a loop

Tags: c, linked-list

I made this program to learn about linked lists as I am just starting out with them. The program terminates immediately after the statement "Enter the amount of pesticide"(it is a school assignment). Also, I am unsure how do I keep the length of the list limited to the size input by the user.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct plants{
    int val;
    struct plants *next;
};

void printlist();

int main(){
    struct plants* head = NULL;
    struct plants* current= head;
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct plants));
    int counter,size;

    printf("Enter the number of plants\n");

    scanf("%d",&size);

    printf("Enter the amount of pesticide each plant has.\n");

    while(current!=NULL){
        scanf("%d",current->val);
        current= current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `current` is null when you start the loop, as the reason it won't even enter your loop

Comment: @sameera sy What do I initialise it to? I have tried 0 with the same result.

Comment: You need to make `current` point to head. As it is not pointing at anything when loop starts. And you have to allocate memory for every new node as loop iterates.

Comment: 'What do I initialise it to? I have tried 0 with the same result' Aaarrghhhh!

Comment: use this set of statements `struct plants* head = NULL;head = malloc(sizeof(struct plants)); struct plants* current= head;`

Comment: @Harris I have pointed current to head. And should I put malloc for new nodes into the loop?

Comment: delcare the current after you malloc

Comment: @Martin James I am just starting out bro...

Comment: you pointed `current` to `head`, and then you make `head` point to newly allocated memory. How will `current` start pointing to the memory automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int size = 0;        
    printf("Enter the number of plants\n");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    printf("Enter the amount of pesticide each plant has.\n");
```

You have to allocate the memory for each node inside the `while` loop. If you like to add the new node at the end of the list notice the end of the list by a pointer to the pointer at the end of the list. Apart form this you have to pass the addres of the value to be read to `scanf`:

```
    struct plants * head = NULL;
    struct plants ** current = &head; // current refers there, where next node has to be placed
    while( count < size ) // do it for "size" nodes
    {
        *current  = malloc(sizeof(struct plants)); // allocate memory for the node right to target 
        scanf( "%d", &((*current)->val));          // read the data
        (*current)->next = NULL;                   // node is last node in list, so its successor is NULL
        current = &((*current)->next);             // step on forward
        count ++;                                  // increment number of nodes
    }
```

Note since the type of `current` is `struct plants **` this codes puts the new node to `head` for the first element of the list and to `(*current)->next` for all further nodes of the list.

It would be easier to add the new node at the head of the list:

```
    struct plants * head = NULL; // init head with NULL (this becomes end of the list)
    while( count < size ) // do it for "size" nodes
    {
        struct plants * current = malloc(sizeof(struct plants)); // allocate memory for the node 
        scanf( "%d", &current->val);       // read the data
        current->next = head;              // successor of node is head
        head = current;                    // new node is head of list
        count ++;                          // increment number of nodes
    }
```

This will print your list:

```
    struct plants *temp = head;
    while( temp != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d ", temp->val );
        temp = temp->next;
    }
```

Don't forget to free the list at the end of your program:

```
    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        struct plants *next = head->next;
        free( head );
        head = next; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you use the while loop at the end?

Comment: @cenobia The last `while` loop is to `free` the memory allocated by `malloc`. Ther has to be one `free` for each `malloc`.

Comment: I noticed you used `&counter->val` and `*(current->val)`. Cant we use `counter->val` in both places?

Comment: @cenobia In the first case the type f `current` is `struct plants **`, but in the second case it is `struct plants *`. So the address of member `val` is `&(*current)->val` for the first case and `&current->val` for the second case.

Comment: Okay. And when I try to print the list using your code, it keeps on printing absurd integers(infinite loop),

Comment: @cenobia I tried out both cases. I used all the code of my answer and it worked fine for me. Did you `#include<malloc.h>`?

Comment: I did. I found the error. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct plants* head = malloc(sizeof(struct plants));//declare an initialize in memory
struct plants* current= head;
int i = 0;
struct plants* aux = NULL;
while(i ++ < size)
{
    aux = malloc(sizeof(struct plants)); // used for new values
    scanf("%d", aux->val);
    aux->next = NULL;
    current->next = aux;
    current = aux;
}
```

Loop while you have less than the quantity required by user. Use an auxiliar node. Read the value, set the `current` next position to the aux node, the aux node to null and set the `current` node to `aux` to be sure you are at the last node from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of things to be corrected, check for the code below. and should be pretty easy for a beginner to understand. I haven't changed the format of your code for ease of understanding

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct plants{
    int val;
    struct plants *next;
};

void printlist();

int main(){
    int i;
    struct plants* head = NULL,*temp=NULL;
    struct plants* current= head;
    int counter,size;
    printf("Enter the number of plants\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&size);  
    printf("Enter the amount of pesticide each plant has.\n");
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        temp = malloc(sizeof(struct plants));
        scanf("%d",&temp->val);
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            head=temp;
            current=head;
        }
        else
        {   
            current->next=temp;
            current=temp;
        }
    }
    current = head;
    while(current!=NULL){
        printf("%d\t",current->val);
        current= current->next;
    }
}
```